# why method post not found in Illuminate\support\facade\input

Tags: laravel, input, laravel-5.3

I work with `laravael 5.3.9` .
In my controller I use

`Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;`

But when I try to get input from a user form using method post like that :

```
function add(){
    $fullName = Input::post('fullName' , 'test');
```

I get this error .

`the only method that Input class has is "get" .`

I dont want that in my system I want to work with method `post` , `delete` , `put` ....

Comment: What have u defined in your ``route.php`` file. Have you defined route there?. In you add function, you missed ending bracket or its just type error here!? Put your code here to get better idea about your error.

Comment: The relevanr commandin routes/web.php file is : 
Route::match(['get' , 'post'], 'area_owners/add' , 'area_owners@add');
the relevant code in controller is : 
function add(){
     $fullName = Input::post('fullName');
}

Comment: try below code in your controller, and let me know. ``Input::post`` is not used, instead use ``Request facade``.

Answer (score 0):

I guess, `Input::post` method is not used with L5.3. Use the Request facade OR `$request` to get your input variable.

Try this in your controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class area_owners extends Controller 
{ 
    function add(Request $request)
    { 
        // I assume all these input variable have same name in you FORM.
        $fullName = $request->input('fullName'); 
        $smsCode  = $request->input('smsCode');
        $authorizationId =  $request->input('authorizationId');
        $areaNumber‌​ =  $request->input('areaNumber‌​');
        $neigh_project_Id =  $request->input('neigh_project_Id');

        $area_owners = DB::table('area_owners')
            ->insert(['fullName'=>$fullName,
                    'smsCode'=>$smsCode,
                    'authorizationId'=>$authorizationId,
                    'are‌​aNumer'=>$areaNumber‌​,
                    'neigh_project_Id'=‌​>$neigh_project_Id])‌​; 
    return view('area_owners_add', ['area_owners' => $area_owners]); 
    } 
}
```

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Yes it worked partially ... the form was submitted and the row was add to the table but it's exactly like GET method because all parameters were displayed in url :
http://localhost:8000/area_owners/add?fullName=%D7%93%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99+%D7%A1%D7%9C%D7%A2&phone=05485887732&email=danielgontar%40gmail.com&forSale=1&dateIn=2016-08-16&smsCode=1&authorizationId=1&areaNumber=1&neigh_project_Id=1
and i dont want that

Comment: What method you are posting your ``form``. In your ``View file``, check for form tag. ``<form method='post' > ... ``

Comment: Sorry , I think you are right ... I forgot to chabge the method in my form to post from get ... fixing the problem and updating u . I think you gave the correct solution.

Comment: I am sure, this will resolve your error. If it had helped, please accept my answer. Happy coding laravel.

Comment: TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 67
same problem when you switch to post method
<form action="http://localhost:8000/area_owners/add" method="post">
    fullname:<input type="text" name="fullName">
    ...
    smsCode:<input type="text" name="smsCode">
    authorizationId:<input type="text" name="authorizationId">
    areaNumber:<input type="text" name="areaNumber">
    neigh_project_Id:<input type="text" name="neigh_project_Id">
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>

Comment: add this ``{{ csrf_field() }}`` after the form tag.

Comment: @DanielGontar, i hope your query has been resolved. If yes, then kindly accept my answer by clicking on the check-mark. Thank you. In case any query let me k now.